# How to Install freqrade in Anaconda?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, ta-lib

I have been trying many methods to install freqtrade in anaconda but I am always getting an error. The most simple code that I thought would work is:

```
pip install freqtrade
```

It only gives me the following error:

```
Building wheel for TA-Lib (setup.py): started
Building wheel for TA-Lib (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Successfully built sdnotify yarl
Failed to build py-find-1st blosc TA-Lib
```

How can I install freqtrade directly from my Jupyter Notebook?

I have looked at the installation instructions on: https://www.freqtrade.io/en/2020.7/installation/#windows - Also with no success.

Thank you!

Comment: You should follow `Install ta-lib` section of instructions. TA-Lib is a library written in C. It must be built on PC to prepare a binary .dll/.so. The `TA-Lib` that `freqtrade` is trying to install is a Python **wrapper** for this library (.dll/.so file). That's why it fail to build if original C library can't be found on PC. You better first build and install ta-lib from C sources, then `pip install ta-lib` to make sure it works. And then `pip install freqtrade`.

Answer (score 0):

TA-Lib is a library written in C. It must be built on PC to prepare a binary `.dll` or`.so` files. The TA-Lib that freqtrade is trying to install is just a Python wrapper for this library. That's why it fail to build if original C library can't be found on PC. You better first build and install ta-lib from C sources, then `pip install ta-lib` to make sure it works. And then `pip install freqtrade`

I was able to install TA-Lib and freqtrade on Jupyter Notebook with following:

```
!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

!tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
%cd ta-lib/
!./configure --prefix=$HOME
!make
!make install

!TA_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib TA_INCLUDE_PATH=~/include pip install ta-lib

!pip install freqtrade
```

Comment: This seems to be the best code online - thank you! However, I am getting the following error when i run these lines of code: !./configure --prefix=$HOME
!make
!make install
Output:
'/configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'TA_LIBRARY_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: `make` shall be available after successfull `configure` and `configure` should be performed in `ta-lib` subfolder. Are you sure you are in right subfolder? Perhaps tar didn't unpack the sources... Use `!pwd` and `!ls` to find out where are you now. You should be in `ta-lib` subfolder after `%cd ta-lib/`